# Unable to Register Windows phone App in Facebook Developer site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, windows-store

We are trying to register Windows phone App in facebook developer portal as mentioned here :

[developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/windows-phone)

We have an App ID : 97f5ba9cfda14c6485b800beb75642** (removed last two chars)

But when we try to insert it in Facebook developer portal it shows an error :
App ID should start with s-1-***

According to link I'd mention above product ID should not contain dashes between product ID.

It seems there's a bug in developer.facebook website which doesn't allow us to enter a product ID.

Earlier facebook had two options for Windows app registration :
- Windows store App ID
- Windows Phone App ID

Now they unified it into a single field, which is blocking our App.

Well we got stuck with this. Any recommendation would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a bug in the Facebook UI, i'd recommend filing a bug report in the bug tracker on developers.facebook.com

Comment: @Igy, we did file a bug/question through facebook report option. How it could possible that facebook doesn't support for windows phone 8 option in their developer site  :(

Answer (score 0):

I have UWP Application that is connected to facebook with help of Azure Mobile App.
Here is link with manual:
[How to configure your App Service application to use Facebook login](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/)